# Laravel Homestead, Can't Get Xip.io To Work?

Tags: laravel, homestead, xip.io

I have tried googling and come up with nothing. I have followed the instructions on setting up my host's file and the `Homestead.yaml` file. I am on a new Mac and want to set up Laravel Homestead?

Here is my hosts file:

```
192.168.10.10    etk.local.192.68.0.74.xip.io:8000
192.168.10.10    games.local.192.168.0.74.xip.io:8000
```

Here is my **Homestead.yaml**:

```
    ip: "192.168.10.10"
    memory: 2048
    cpus: 2
    provider: virtualbox

    authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

    keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

   folders:
- map: ~/Web/Projects/Laravel/2021/etk
  to: /home/vagrant/code/etk

- map: ~/Web/Projects/Laravel/2021/games
  to: /home/vagrant/code/games

   sites:
- map: etk.local
  to: /home/vagrant/code/etk/public
  php: "7.1"

- map: etk.local.192.168.0.74.xip.io
  to: /home/vagrant/code/etk/public
  php: "7.1"

- map: games.local
  to: /home/vagrant/code/games/public
  php: "8.0"

- map: games.local.192.168.0.74.xip.io
  to: /home/vagrant/code/games/public
  php: "8.0"
```

I can access localhost:8000 in my browser, but not the URL `etk.local.192.168.0.74.xip.io:8000`, nor the games URL? All I can see when I check in Chrome browser for instance, is the error message: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`?
Can someone help with this? Many thanks.

Update: When I run vagrant up, I see some warning messages that were not there before? Maybe someone could shed some light on them?

```
==> homestead: Detected mount owner ID within mount options.
```

Thanks again.